# New yesod app not starting

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying create a new yesod app, as I am new to Yesod and Haskell, I'm following the instructions on this page.   http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart

So far I've set my system up to run with Stackage Server and installed the neccessary build tools, I've ran a yesod init command and build the app, but for some reason, when I cd into my app, and try to run cabal sandbox init, I'm getting the error

cabal: unrecognised command: sandbox (try --help)

when I run cabal --version I get this

cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library

and my .bashrc has this line

export PATH="~/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.20/bin:/opt/ghc/7.8.3/bin:$PATH"

Any ideas why this is?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to install a newer version of cabal. I'm not entirely certain but I think I remember haskell platform making this is a bit of a pain, if that's what you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `/opt/cabal/1.20/bin` contain version 1.20 of cabal? If so, put that directory in front of your PATH - i.e. replace the `export PATH=` in your .bashrc with:

```
export PATH="/opt/cabal/1.20/bin:~/.cabal/bin:/opt/ghc/7.8.3/bin:$PATH"
```

Reload your .bashrc and see what `cabal sandbox --help` reports.